# Problem transmitting date over the network

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, datetime, timezone

I have an MVC application that sends a date value from a server in USA as JSON format and it is displayed in a PC in Chile.

Server side has this action in controller:

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> GetFacturas(Models.DataTableAjaxPostModel model)
    {
        // Some other code in between
        // ----
        return Json(fecha);   // fecha has the value of 2019-04-16 00:00:00
    }
```

By using  Chrome development tool, I see that the date is received in JSON object as 1555383600000.

By using the site https://www.epochconverter.com/ I translated that date to a human readable format and I saw that it is:

```
GMT: Tuesday, 16 April 2019 3:00:00
Your time zone: Monday, 15 April 2019 23:00:00 GMT-04:00
```

Even when MVC controller got date as 2019-04-16 00:00:00, it seems when Json serialized it, it was converted to GMT using -3 time zone, so, finally that GMT date was received by client computer, which in turn converted the date back to local time applying -4 operation.

Operating system is configured as Time Zone -4, and MVC application is configured this way in web.config file:

```
<globalization culture="es-CL" uiCulture="es-CL" />
```

How can I avoid this problem?

EDIT:

"fecha" variable is a DateTime object returned from a database, this way:

```
var fecha = db.Entity.Select(f => f.DatetimeField).FirstOrDefault();
```

Of course I simplified the query, but the fact is that "fecha", before returning the function, is a DateTime object whose value is 2019-04-16 00:00:00.

Regards

Jaime

Comment: The user will see the server time, irrespective of its location. You need to return the datetime as .ToLocalTime().DateTime if you need the local time. Your question does not reflect wjat you are expecting.

Comment: @BalajiBirajdar - `ToLocalTime` uses the time zone of the *server*.  It has no understanding of the client's local time zone.  Also, you're assuming `fetcha` is a `DateTimeOffset` type, but this was not stated in the question.

Comment: @jstuardo - Your question doesn't give us a complete picture.  We would need to know the data type of the `fetcha` variable you are serializing, and we would also need to see an example of how you instantiate it, and what the serialized form appears as.  Then we'd need to see your client-side code to know how you deserialize it. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help center.  Also, you should understand the time zones have nothing to do with culture settings.  They are completely separate concepts.

Comment: @MattJohnson I have edited the question. You can reproduce it simple by creating a DateTime object with the value I have, and then return it as a Json object. I am not deserializing direcly, because I am using DataTable jquery plugin. However, it doen't matter. The fact  is that if I use https://www.epochconverter.com/ page to see the value received by client, it is 1 hour less than the real time. That demonstrate that this has nothing to do with the client that shows the time. The date and time is serialized incorrectly by Json object.

Comment: @MattJohnson the exact question could be, why does Newtonsoft Json object serialize a DateTime object as UTC using Time Zone -3 instead of -4 which is configured in operating system. That causes the date and time in the example, to be transmited as 2019-04-16 03:00:00... so, when deserializing, time zone -4 is used, causing the date and time to be displayed as 2019-04-15 23:00:00. Is there a way Newtonsoft Json object to be configured to use the correct time zone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the value in your JSON looks something like `"/Date(1555383600000)/"`, which is the older [JSON date format](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx).  With this format, the local time zone of the server is applied when the `.Kind` property of the `DateTime` value is either `DateTimeKind.Local` or `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.

Even if the value stored in your database is in UTC, there's no way for EF to know that, so it is being set as unspecified.  You can set it yourself with:

```
fetcha = DateTime.SpecifyKind(fetch, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Now you'll find that the value gets serialized as `"/Date(1555372800000)/"`.

Current versions of ASP.Net and Newtonsoft.Json use the ISO 8601 format instead.  Without any changes to your code, your values are serialized based on the `.Kind` property as follows:

- With `DateTimeKind.Unspecified, as`"2019-04-16T00:00:00.0000000"`
- With `DateTimeKind.Utc`, as  `"2019-04-16T00:00:00.0000000Z"`
- With `DateTimeKind.Local`, as `"2019-04-16T00:00:00.0000000-03:00"` (using the server's tz offset)

You can switch between the two formats using the [`DateFormatHandling` setting](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateFormatHandling.htm), but I recommend leaving it at the default of `IsoDateFormat`.  See also [Serializing Dates in JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm).

Client-side deserialization is also a factor.  If you are handed a timestamp (with the old format), then that timestamp is aligned to UTC.  If you are handed a string (with the new format), the timestamp is influenced by the offset in the string, or by the local browser time zone if there is no offset provided.  Additionally, the `Date` object in JavaScript has many functions that can *only* use the browser's local time zone.

All things considered, it can be very difficult to get a date-only value to serialize end-to-end without being affected by time zone in some way.  You can try the above approaches, but if indeed you just want to save, restore, display and transmit the same date-only value, then you might also just consider sending a string without the time, as in `"2019-04-16"`:

```
return Json(fetch.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture"));
```

Comment: Date and time in database is in client local time (time in Chile). Furthermore, I am using last version of Newtonsoft library and last version of MVC, so I am wondering why the old format is used. I am using Controller.Json method to return a JsonResult to client. You mean that before that call I have to reassign "fecha" variable to the call to SpecifyKind? I have thought about transmitting a string, but I think that should be the last resource, because DataTable plugin expects a date and time. If I get a string instead of date, I would need to program a custom formatter for DataTable plugin,

Comment: I have finally used .ToString("s") to the date before serializing. That way, client could deserialize correctly to a date and time object before applying date format, and then, to be able to display in the DataTable.